# file limit while uploading folder

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, webkit

I am using webkit directory to upload folder on server. Folder is uploading fine on server. But when there are more then 20 files in the folder then it uploads only first 20 files.

My php code for uploading folder on server is as follows:

```
  <input type="file" name="files[]" onchange="formSubmit()" id="files" webkitdirectory=""/>
```

upload script is as follows:

```
<?php    
                               $count = 0;

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

        foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $i => $name) {
            if (strlen($_FILES['files']['name'][$i]) > 1) {


                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i], 'upload/'.$name)) {
                    $count++;

                }
            }
        }
        echo $count;
    }

    ?>
```

I have echo $_FILES. it is also showing 20 files. I have 50 files in my folders what i think is that there is limit of 20 files to be send to server so my question is how to upload all files to server?

Comment: add else condition to your if (move_uploaded_file(..)) { .. } to see if you get any error

Comment: i have added else condition but it is not going to else part.

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is regulated by the [`max_file_uploads`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.max-file-uploads) setting; the default value is 20, so it won't allow more.

> If more files are uploaded than the limit, then `$_FILES` will stop processing files once the limit is reached. For example, if max_file_uploads is set to 10, then `$_FILES` will never contain more than 10 items.

From: http://php.net/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls

You can change this setting in either the php.ini or per-directory configuration files, e.g. .htaccess, but **not** via `ini_set()`.

Comment: how can i change this setting from perdirectory configuration?

Comment: @MuneemHabib That depends; if you're using Apache, you use the `php_value` for it.